# Prove that there is infinitely graphs which satisfied the ....

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is an abstract finite group and given natural numbers $n$ and $m$ that
that satisfy $n\geq 3,2\leq m \leq n$. Prove that there are exist infinitely  $\Gamma$ graphs with the properties :

a.  Aut($\Gamma$) is isomorphic to $G$
b. $\Gamma$ is n-regular
c. The chromatic number of $\Gamma$ is $m$

The general ways is constructing the cayley graph $\Gamma=\Gamma(G,\Omega)$. First, i took $G=(Z_{n}\times Z_{m},+)$ for the vertices and then took the all generator(except identity) of $Z_{n}\times Z_{m}$ as the elements of $\Omega$. So, from the definition of cayley graph i produces the all points with this ways:

a)$g,h\in G$ be vertices in the graph $\Gamma$,
b)Suppose the  of $\Gamma$ is defined by $\Omega=\{s_{1},s_{2},\cdots,s_{k}\}$,
c)Then, $h=g+s_{i}$ for some $i$.

It can be seen that a vertex $g$ has degree-$k$ and every other vertices in the graph $\Gamma$ is produced in the same way, hence all vertices have degree-$k$. Therefore, the graph $\Gamma$ (cayley graph) is a $k$-regular graph. And this is the problem , i realized that the $|\Omega|=k$ which is how many generators that $G$ have. I thought the order of $Z_{n}\times Z_{m}$ is $\phi(m)\times\phi(n)$(correction is needed, because i asked the gpt for that). I tried the $Z_{4}\times Z_{3}$ it has $|\Omega|=4$ but $Z_{3}\times Z_{3}$ it has $|\Omega|=0$. Is there any another approach to prove?